# Как получить ключ API V2 в DialogFlow из JSON файла?

Tags: json, api, dialogflow

Есть те, кто работал с DialogFlow после 31 мая? Там API V2 теперь и ключ нужно получить из JSON файла, в инете инфы толком нет

[image: JSON файл]

Answer (score 0):

В данном вашем примере у вас ключ будет privete_key, при этом их там несколько и есть символ \n он и разделяет api ключи!